# how to create or update product attribute value for specific categories? Magento 2

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, custom-attributes, category-products

I created an numeric attribute, and product has assigned 2 categories (parent category and subcategory), is it possible update product attribute only for subcategory? or is it possible create custom product attribute only for subcategory? This would apply for all products.
[image]

MOTOR (Subcategory)
Colecciones (Parent Category)

I need to set numeric attribute value (3) in MOTOR and that in the parent category the value is still kept at (0)

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Can you please elaborate more..what do you mean by pattern?

Comment: Sorry Ankit, is parent category, i edited question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand why you want to create product attribute as I will try to give a answer:

Method 1: You can create category attribute and set values according to your Parent and Subcategory.

Method 2: If you want to create product attribute only, in this case you can create category and product attribute both and match there values. So if there is subcategory and value of category attribute is enable so it will show your product attribute value.

May be I am wrong here but I can not comment whole answer. Let me know if you need anything.

Comment: I created an numeric attribute and need to set value only for subcategory, i need to exclude value attribute for parent category page

Comment: Yes so you should create numeric attribute of category not for products.